# Google ML Kit Dart Flutter: The method 'InputImagePlaneMetadata' isn't defined for the type '_MyHomePageState'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-mlkit

I'm building a face detection app with flutter using Google's ML Kit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoLMG.png)

However VSCode doesn't find certain methods:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQwQK.png)

My imports are fine I think:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lv6yG.png)

How to solve this? Thanks!

reinstalled all packages, installed the google ml kit commons package, run pub get

Answer (score 1):

If you search for the class **InputImagePlaceMetadata**, you will see it does not exist in the [mlkit commons library](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_mlkit_commons/latest/google_mlkit_commons/google_mlkit_commons-library.html).

It exists in the package called [Satya_TextOcr_Package](https://pub.dev/documentation/satya_textocr/latest/src_path_vision_vision/InputImagePlaneMetadata-class.html) (for some reason).

Did you mean to use [InputImageMetadata](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_mlkit_commons/latest/google_mlkit_commons/InputImageMetadata-class.html) instead?

I see you have not imported the MLKit Commons Library.

Comment: I'm to run this repo, the author had it running with exact the same packages as I have:
https://github.com/hamza372/FlutterRealTimeFaceDetectionStarter2022/blob/main/lib/main.dart

Comment: @xhc2407 - The repository you linked to has not had any change in 10 months and if you look at the pubspec.yaml file, it does not have any of the dependencies you have declared. I would import the ml_kit_commons library. If my answer helped you, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a breaking change on `google_mlkit_commons`, read more [here](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mlkit_commons/changelog).

```
0.4.0 
BREAKING: Update InputImage.
BREAKING: Rename InputImageData -> InputImageMetadata.
BREAKING: Remove InputImagePlaneMetadata.
Only support nv21 for Android and bgra8888 for iOS.
```

After this breaking change, you don't need to calculate plane data anymore. Some related functions need to be updated as well. Here is a sample of what works in the current version:

```
// ** This calculation is no longer needed, should delete:
// final planeData = cameraImage.planes.map(
//   (Plane plane) {
//     return InputImagePlaneMetadata( // <--- Removed
//       bytesPerRow: plane.bytesPerRow,
//       height: plane.height,
//       width: plane.width,
//     );
//   },
// ).toList();

final inputImageData = InputImageMetadata(
  size: imageSize,
  rotation: imageRotation,
  format: inputImageFormat,
  bytesPerRow: cameraImage.planes[0].bytesPerRow,
);

final inputImage = InputImage.fromBytes(
  bytes: bytes,
  metadata: inputImageData,
);

return inputImage;
```

Alternatively, if you downgrade your plugin, you can keep your old code working. For example, in your pubspec.yaml, use an older version like so:

```
  google_mlkit_image_labeling: 0.5.0
  google_mlkit_object_detection: 0.6.0
```