how to fix this error in flutter using google_ml_kit: ^0.16.3 in face detection?
As you see here this is my code and these are the errors you will find my full void code down and I'm using:
google_ml_kit: ^0.16.3

this project is for face detection using the camera
InputImageRotationMethods: Undefined name 'InputImageRotationMethods'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.dartundefined_identifier
InputImageFormatMethods: Undefined name 'InputImageFormatMethods'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.dartundefined_identifier
InputImagePlaneMetadata: The method 'InputImagePlaneMetadata' isn't defined for the type '_RecognitionScreenState'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'InputImagePlaneMetadata'.dartundefined_method
InputImageData: The method 'InputImageData' isn't defined for the type '_RecognitionScreenState'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'InputImageData'.dartundefined_method
final inputImage =         InputImage.fromBytes(bytes: bytes, inputImageData: inputImageData); The named parameter 'metadata' is required, but there's no corresponding argument. Try adding the required argument.dartmissing_required_argument (new) InputImage InputImage.fromBytes({required Uint8List bytes, required InputImageMetadata metadata})
this is the code i created check it and correct it please for me:
Future<void> _processCameraImage(CameraImage image) async {
    final WriteBuffer allBytes = WriteBuffer();
    for (Plane plane in image.planes) {
      allBytes.putUint8List(plane.bytes);
    }
    final bytes = allBytes.done().buffer.asUint8List();

    final Size imageSize =
        Size(image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble());

    final InputImageRotation imageRotation =
        InputImageRotationMethods.fromRawValue(
                _cameraController!.description.sensorOrientation) ??
            InputImageRotation.Rotation_0deg;

    final InputImageFormat inputImageFormat =
        InputImageFormatMethods.fromRawValue(image.format.raw) ??
            InputImageFormat.NV21;

    final planeData = image.planes.map(
      (Plane plane) {
        return InputImagePlaneMetadata(
          bytesPerRow: plane.bytesPerRow,
          height: plane.height,
          width: plane.width,
        );
      },
    ).toList();

    final inputImageData = InputImageData(
      size: imageSize,
      imageRotation: imageRotation,
      inputImageFormat: inputImageFormat,
      planeData: planeData,
    );

    final inputImage =
        InputImage.fromBytes(bytes: bytes, inputImageData: inputImageData);

    _detectFaces(inputImage);
  }

I really need help guys soon.

did you fix it? im having troubles with this too

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76893505/google-ml-kit-dart-flutter-the-method-inputimageplanemetadata-isnt-defined-f
